# Adding an AND clause to a regex

Tags: regex

I have this simple regex,

```
[\d]{1,5}
```

that matches any integer between 0 and 99999.

How would I modify it so that it didn't match 0, but matches 01 and 10, etc?

I know there is a way to do an OR like so...

```
[\d]{1,5}|[^0]{1}
```

(doesn't make much sense)

There a way to do an AND?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

probably better off with something like:

0*[1-9]+[\d]{0,4}

If I'm right that translates to "zero or more zeros followed by at least one  of the characters included in '1-9' and then up to 4 trailing decimal characters"

Mike

Comment: Your expression would not match "10".

Comment: Your expression also matches 00. It isn't explicitly denied, but i'm not sure if that is the intent.

Comment: Changing the start of the regex from 0* to 0? would limit it to only allow 0 or 1 leading zeroes, preventing 007 from matching.  Note, however, that any leading zero(es) will not be counted in the 5-digit limit, which may or may not be desirable.

Comment: I think you need to drop the '+' sign after the [1-9], otherwise you will match more than 5 digits - eg 1110123 would be matched.  See Chris Marasti-Georg for a good format.

Answer (score 3):

I think the simplest way would be:

```
[1-9]\d{0,4}
```

throw that between a ^$ if it makes sense in your case, and if so, add a 0* to the beginning:

```
^0*[1-9]\d{0,4}$
```

Comment: It won't limit the string to 5 characters, but is otherwise good.

Comment: true - luckily, he didn't say he was limiting to 5 characters.  He just said he wanted 1-99999

Answer (score 2):

My vote is to keep the regex simple and do that as a separate compare outside the regex.  If the regex passes, convert it to an int and make sure the converted value is > 0.

But I know that sometimes one regex in a config file or validation property on a control is all you get.

Answer (score 2):

How about an OR between single digit numbers you will accept and multiple-digit numbers:

**^[1-9]$|^\d{2,5}$**

Comment: That would still match 00, which does not seem to be the poster's goal

Comment: The second part could be [1-9]\d{1,4} if you wanted to disallow "00000".

Comment: Could add 0{0,4} to the front of both expressions to allow leading zeros, but of course that might allow too many digits :-)

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, 101 is no problem (note I said 0{0,4} so that allows no leading zeros)

Answer (score 2):

I think a negative lookahead would work.  Try this:

```
#!/bin/perl -w

while (<>)
{
    chomp;
    print "OK: $_\n" if m/^(?!0+$)\d{1,6}$/;
}
```

Example trace:

```
0
00
000
0000
00000
000000
0000001
000001
OK: 000001
101
OK: 101
01
OK: 01
00001
OK: 00001
1000
OK: 1000
101
OK: 101
```

Answer (score 1):

By using look-aheads you can achieve the effect of AND.

```
^(?=regex1)(?=regex2)(?=regex3).*
```

Though there is a bug in Internet Explorer, that sometimes doesn't treat `(?= )` as zero-width.

http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/regex-lookahead-bug

In your case:

```
^(?=\d{1,5}$)(?=.*?[1-9]).*
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are searching for 2 different conditions. Why not break it out to 2 expressions? It might be simpler and more readable.

```
var str = user_string;
if ('0' != str && str.matches(/^\d{1,5}$/) {
    // code for match
}
```

or the following if a string of 0's is not valid as well

```
var str = user_string;
if (!str.matches(/^0+$/) && str.matches(/^\d{1,5}$/) {
    // code for match
}
```

Just because you can do it all in one regex doesn't mean that you should.

Comment: The 2nd regex would be better as a simple if condition.  Once you know that it's numeric, you can just convert to an int and check that this int is > 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
^([1-9][0-9]{0,4}|[0-9]{,1}[1-9][0-9]{,3}|[0-9]{,2}[1-9][0-9]{,2}|[0-9]{,3}[1-9][0-9]|[0-9]{,4}[1-9])$
```

Not pretty, but it should work.  This is more of a brute force approach.  There's a better way to do it via grouping as well, but I'm drawing a blank on the actual implementation at the moment.